For EEG, I am working on receiving uint8list data in bundles of 33 pieces × 250 bundles per second from a Bluetooth device
I am currently developing an Android app using Flutter. For EEG, I am working on receiving uint8list data in bundles of 33 pieces × 250 bundles per second from a Bluetooth device. The second value in each 33-piece data set represents the packet number. Therefore, it should increment sequentially (1, 2, 3, ...) without any issues. However, sometimes the order of the data gets mixed up, duplicated, or lost. The issue is that when I connect the Bluetooth device to a computer, there is no such error rate. Could this be a problem with the Android device and Bluetooth communication? The Flutter code is simple; I am just using the bluetooth_serial package to receive data through connection!.input!.listen((data)).
Thank you!
The packet numbers are mixed up, lost, and duplicated.
It is suspicious that there are no errors when connecting through a desktop.
